# StackExchange.Redis how to query all keys only on one db

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, nosql

I am newbie in redis, Now I want get all keys in one db without knowing about keys or pattern of keys. After googling,I found a sodu code about my issue, but i have no key pattern or data field in this code:

```
 var connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(new ConfigurationOptions
    {
        EndPoints = { { DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port } },
        Password = DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Password
    });

    var server = connection.GetServer(host: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Url, 
                                      port: DemoSettings.CustomerRedisCache.Port);
    var cadena = "cust:" + data.SearchString.Replace(' ', ':')+"*";
    var valores = server.Keys(pattern: cadena);
```

Answer (score 16):

According to [this link](http://tostring.it/2015/04/23/An-easy-way-to-use-StackExchange-Redis-copy/), the following code gets all the keys:

```
var keys = myCacheClient.SearchKeys("*");
```

Comment: what is `myCacheClient`?

Comment: var myCacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(connectionMultiplexer, newtonsoftSerializer); Please refer to the link and install StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core and StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft